# jQuery: How Do I Append Text From textarea To paragraph After I Presses Enter?

Tags: jquery, html, append, enter

I want to essentially move the text the user types from the `textarea` into the paragraph of my choice when the user `presses enter`. The problem is enter is already programmed into `textarea`. It's function is to make a new line but I want to replace that function with:

When the user presses enter it moves there text from the textarea to

Here is my html code for the paragraph and textarea:

```
<hr id="LineOne">
<p id="UserInput"></p>
<hr id="LineOne">
<textarea placeholder="Type Message Here:"></textarea>
```

And here is my jQuery (Here is where I think the problem is happening so pay more attention here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').bind("enterKey",function(e){
        textarea.moveTo('#UserInput');
    });
});
    $('textarea').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
        }
});
```

I am very noobie/newbie with jQuery and I found the from another problem in Stack overflow and edited it to fit my needs but it isn't working the way I want it to can you tell me why it wont work and how to fix it.

And also, how can I make so after the user makes a message it puts a space after the message they sent so it doesn't append every message they make the the same line?

**I want to make it so if I remove the text from textarea, paragraph (or UserInput) will still have that text saved.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might looking for this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea').keyup(function(e) {
    // Regex for matching new lines which will be replaced with <br />
    // to make new line onto the paragraph.
    var newval = $(this).val().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    var para = $('#myparagraph');
    
    // Keycode 13 is the Enter key
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      // Append the all text inside the textarea into paragraph
      para.append(newval);
      $(this).val(''); // Clear the textbox
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr/><p id="myparagraph"></p><hr/>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: This did move the text over but, when you remove it from textarea it also gets removed from <p>.

Comment: Yes that's what I want.

Comment: you're welcome, but it would be better if you clear the textbox every time you hit the enter key `$(this).val('');` what I added in my answer.

Comment: This helps alot and it makes the process flow more smoothly

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery to do this. Simply do:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

input.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) { // when a key is pressed
  if (event.keyCode == 13 && input.value != '\n') { // if the key is the enter key
    output.innerHTML += '<br>' + input.value;
    input.value = '';
  }
});

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) { // when a key is released
  if (event.keyCode == 13) { // if the key is the enter key
    input.value = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<hr id="LineOne">
<p id="output"></p>
<hr id="LineOne">
<textarea id="input" placeholder="Type Message Here:"></textarea>
```

Comment: That is what I want but, the text doesn't stay in the paragraph if you removed it from textarea. That's my intent.

Comment: I fixed it - is that better?

Comment: Yes I need that as well

Comment: That would be much easier. I fixed it :). Feel free to ask if there are any parts you don't understand.